# Removing AVPlayerViewController and observer doesn't seem to be working

Tags: swift, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter, avplayerviewcontroller

Here is how I create my AVPlayerViewController in my custom view:

```
private func configureAVPlayer(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    self.avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    self.avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    guard self.avPlayer != nil && self.avPlayerController != nil else {
        return
    }

        self.avPlayerController!.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.avPlayerController!.player = self.avPlayer!
        self.avPlayerController!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
        self.avPlayerController!.view.clipsToBounds = true
        self.avPlayerController!.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.avPlayerController!.view.frame = self.imageView.frame

            self.mediaView.addSubview(self.avPlayerController!.view)
            self.mediaView.sendSubview(toBack: self.avPlayerController!.view)

            self.parentController.addChildViewController(self.avPlayerController!)


            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayer!.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
                print("Replaying")

                self.avPlayer?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                self.avPlayer?.play()
            }

            completion()
        })
    }
}
```

When my view disappears, I want to remove my AVPlayerViewController and it's observer, so I use:

```
    override func removeFromSuperview() {
        avPlayerController?.player?.pause()
        avPlayerController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        avPlayerController?.removeFromParentViewController()
        avPlayerController = nil

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayer!.currentItem)

    }
```

However, the next time I create this view, and call `configureAVPlayer`, the completion for my observer gets called twice and I hear the audio of my video twice, aka two videos playing at once.

Am I not removing the observer correctly?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver

Store reference to notification, then remove observer using stored reference. p.s. Sample code is at the end.

Can I ask, why are You creating and configuring player and controller on the background q.?

Comment: There was some lag when creating this new view and it seemed like it was associated with the player and controller creation because when I put it on a background thread the lag went away, but now I'm running into some other problems that may have to do with that

Comment: You should setup and configure UI elements on main thread. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html